# Can someone explain what each part of this regex means ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s)

Tags: regex

I am trying to find out a regex pattern to check if a password contains at least:
one lowercase letter,
one uppercase letter,
one numeric digit,
and one special character(Symbol)

I came across this regex:  `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s)` but I don't really understand well what each part is doing, If someone has a bit of free time I would be very thankful if you could explain to me what each part does.

Comment: why not just paste the regex into something like https://regexr.com/? there's plenty of tools to explain regexes

Comment: @eis simply because I didn't know something like this exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern contains a number of positive *lookahead* assertions, which are checking for the presence of various things in the input.  Here is an explanation:

```
^                   from the start of the input
(?=.*\d)            assert one or more digits are present
(?=.*[a-z])         assert lowercase letters
(?=.*[A-Z])         assert uppercase letters
(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])  assert one or more characters which are NOT alphanumeric
(?!.*\s)            assert one or more whitespace characters
```

Answer (score 1):

If you paste it into https://regex101.com/ you get this explanation. I suggest you use this site to experiment and understand. Also the explanation is formatted in a much better way

If you want to learn regex you need to start with something simpler

> ^ asserts position at start of a line
> Positive Lookahead (?=.`*`\d)
> Assert that the Regex below matches
> . matches any character (except for line terminators)
> `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
> Positive Lookahead (?=.`*`[a-z])
> Assert that the Regex below matches
> . matches any character (except for line terminators)
> `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> Match a single character present in the list below [a-z]
> a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
> Positive Lookahead (?=.`*`[A-Z])
> Assert that the Regex below matches
> . matches any character (except for line terminators)
> `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
> A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
> Positive Lookahead (?=.`*`[^a-zA-Z0-9])
> Assert that the Regex below matches
> . matches any character (except for line terminators)
> `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> Match a single character not present in the list below [^a-zA-Z0-9]
> a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
> A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
> 0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
> Negative Lookahead (?!.`*`\s)
> Assert that the Regex below does not match
> . matches any character (except for line terminators)
> `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
> Global pattern flags
> g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
> m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Answer (score 1):

You can google the regular expression cheat sheet to have an understanding of it. Here is one that I found useful, https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

You can also look at https://regex101.com/ and play around with regex.